# How to use case statement in mysql query in my case?

Tags: php, html, mysql, case, html-table

I have a utility bill table as follows:

```
table: table_bill
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
id | bill_type | month | year | lastdate | amount | latedate1 | lateamount1 | latedate2 | lateamount2|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 | Electricity | Jan | 2015 | 2015-02-01 | 500 | 2015-03-01 | 550 | 2015-04-01 | 600
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2 | Water | Jan | 2015 | 2015-03-01 | 200 | 2015-04-01 | 250 | 2015-05-01 | 300
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3 | Gas | Jan | 2015 | 2015-02-01 | 800 | 0000-00-00 | NULL | 0000-00-00 | NULL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Table Description:

Electricity and Water bill have fine for Late payment, so those columns are filled with data, on the other hand, Gas bill has no fine for late payment. So, the data of Gas bill is either 0000-00-00 for date or Null for amount.

Now when I want to view unpaid bill on 2015-03-01, then I want the unpaid bill as following table:

```
table: html table
--------------------------------------------------------------
Bill Type | Month | Year | Next Payment Date | Payable Amount
--------------------------------------------------------------
Electricity | Jan | 2015 | 2015-03-01 | 550
--------------------------------------------------------------
Water | Jan | 2015 | 2015-03-01 | 200
--------------------------------------------------------------
Gas | Jan | 2015 | 2015-02-01 | 800
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Explanation: As Electricity bill has fine for late payment and I am viewing bill on 2015-03-01, so the next payment date will be 2015-03-01 and the payable amount is 550 with late fee. On the other hand, Water bill has also fine for late payment, but as the lastdate without late fee is 2015-03-01, so the next payment date is 2015-03-01 and amount is 200. As Gas bill has no late fee, so the next payment date is 2015-02-01 although I am viewing bill on 2015-03-01 and Payable amount is 800.

Question: How to make a SELECT query to pull data from the database table for output the above unpaid bill table?

I want to use CASE statement but not well known about CASE STATEMENT. I have tried with the following query:

```
$today = gmdate('Y-m-d', time()+21600);
SELECT bill_type, month, year, 
CASE bill_type WHEN Electricity AND $today<=lastdate THEN lastdate
WHEN Electricity AND $today<=lastdate1 THEN latedate1
WHEN Electricity AND $today<=lastdate2 THEN lastdate2
WHEN Electricity AND $today<=lastdate3 THEN lastdate3
WHEN Water AND $today<=lastdate1 THEN latedate1
WHEN Water AND $today<=lastdate2 THEN lastdate2
WHEN Water AND $today<=lastdate3 THEN lastdate3
ELSE lastdate END) as ldate,
CASE bill_type WHEN Electricity AND $today<=lastdate THEN amount
WHEN Electricity AND $today<=lastdate1 THEN lateamount1
WHEN Electricity AND $today<=lastdate2 THEN lateamount2
WHEN Electricity AND $today<=lastdate3 THEN lateamount3
WHEN Water AND $today<=lastdate1 THEN lateamount1
WHEN Water AND $today<=lastdate2 THEN lateamount2
WHEN Water AND $today<=lastdate3 THEN lateamount3
ELSE amount END) as amount FROM table_bill
```

But the above query is not working and also it is too big if there will be more bill_type like sanitation, internet, webhost etc. For each bill_type, I have to make two CASE statement and in each CASE statement I have to use WHEN.....THEN a lot of times.

How to make query workable and in simple as far as possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think some normalisation is needed here. Your problem is caused by redundancy in bill table and you should separate late payment charges form bill table - additive charges for reaching concrete latedate level not including bills amount*. This way you could have:

```
SELECT
    bill.type,
    bill.month,
    bill.year,
    (bill.amount + SUM(IFNULL(latecharge.amount, 0))) AS amount
FROM bill
LEFT JOIN latecharge
    ON latecharge.bill_type = bill.type // might be assigned to concrete bill (id)
    AND latecharge.afterdate <= DATE(NOW()) //or some :date parameter
WHERE ...
GROUP BY bill.id
```

*) part of new `latecharge` table based on example for Electricity:

```
id|..bill_type|.afterdate|amount
.1|Electricity|2015-03-01|....50 // additional 50 to Electricity bill's amount after 2015-03-01
.2|Electricity|2015-04-01|....50 // and another 50 after 2015-04-01
```

Comment: No normalization is needed. I have figure out the query. It will be: SELECT bill_type, month, year, CASE WHEN bill_type = 'Electricity' or bill_type='Water' AND lastdate>='$today' THEN lastdate WHEN bill_type = 'Electricity' or bill_type='Water' AND lastdate1>='$today' THEN lastdate1 WHEN bill_type = 'Electricity' or bill_type='Water' AND lastdate2>='$today' THEN lastdate2 ELSE lastdate END as ldate